# Spark Health check scripts

Tags: bash, unix, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I planning for spark streaming on on multi node cluster. What kind of health check scripts do i need to on spark cluster.Can any one provide any sample?
Like to check if spark is running well or not or any node goes down etc..

Comment: Does the provided solution answer your question ? If not please comment on why it doesn't under the provided solution.

Answer (score 0):

Well not all the things you wanted to do comes in one piece.

1. For spark jobs - you need to make a decision on how you want to handle the failures. This is based on your business requirements like - should the entire job fail for one bad row, or just continue job and accumulate bad records. This would be on assumption that all worker nodes are good
2. Based on which distribution you used, you can manage the node health. Cloudera Distribution gives lot of details about the health, and when you see red signals regarding the memory etc.
3. With oozie or any workflow management, you can also configure email alerts for your jobs when they fail